# Why do I get `CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT` from `clSetKernelArg`?

Tags: c++, opencl, opencl-c

I'm almost done rewriting some CUDA code into OpenCL. But I get this terrible runtime error.

The kernel I call takes arguments like this:

```
__kernel void kernel_forwardProject(
  __global float *proj_out,
  __gloabl float *proj_in,
  __global float *vol,
  __read_only image3d_t tex_vol,
  __constant float *transformMatrices,
  __constant float *sourcePositions)
```

I am using the `cl2.hpp` wrapper for OpenCL and when I call the equivalent of `clSetKernelArg` for argument 0, i.e. `proj_out`, `CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT` is returned.

I also get the same result when switching around argument 0 and 1.
I've tried the three ways I know of allocating the device buffers:

```cpp
// 1)
  auto dev_proj_out = cl::Buffer(queue, h_proj_out, h_proj_out + proj_size,
    /*read_only*/false, /*useHostPtr*/true, &err);
// 2)
  auto dev_proj_out = cl::Buffer(ctx, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR,
    proj_size * sizeof(float), (void*)&h_proj_out[0], &err);
// 3)
  auto dev_proj_out = cl::Buffer(ctx, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,
    req_dev_alloc, nullptr, &err);
  queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(dev_proj_out, CL_TRUE, 0, 0, (void *)&h_proj_out[0]);
```

`h_proj_out` is `float*`, `proj_size` is `64*64*16` in the test case.
I've tried all 4 combinations of `false` and `true` for `read_only` and `useHostPtr`.

I check `err` after all OpenCL API calls, there is no errors before `clSetKernelArg`.

I've stepped through the code with gdb for all the combinations, it's always at `clSetKernelArg` for the first argument which gives the error.

I've tried both the [Nvidia](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/opencl-nvidia/) and [Intel CPU](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/intel-opencl-runtime/) OpenCL runtimes. (POCL doesn't support image types for nvidia gpus, so I can't use that)

The host code can be found here: https://gitlab.com/agravgaard/cbctrecon/blob/master/Library/CbctReconLib/rtkExtension/rtkOpenCLForwardProjectionImageFilter.cpp#L130

The OpenCL kernel: 
https://gitlab.com/agravgaard/cbctrecon/blob/master/Library/CbctReconLib/rtkExtension/forward_proj.cl#L71
The kernel compiles without any warnings using the Intel SDK for OpenCL offline compiler (with the same defines as given at runtime).

The error occurs on [line 247](https://gitlab.com/agravgaard/cbctrecon/blob/master/Library/CbctReconLib/rtkExtension/rtkOpenCLForwardProjectionImageFilter.cpp#L247) of the host code. The [KernelFunctor](https://gitlab.com/agravgaard/cbctrecon/blob/master/Library/CbctReconLib/OpenCL/cl2.hpp#L8701) calls [setArgs<>](https://gitlab.com/agravgaard/cbctrecon/blob/master/Library/CbctReconLib/OpenCL/cl2.hpp#L8751) which calls setArg of the kernel, which calls [clSetKernelArg at line 5398 of cl2.hpp](https://gitlab.com/agravgaard/cbctrecon/blob/master/Library/CbctReconLib/OpenCL/cl2.hpp#L5398)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue had two parts comes from mixing devices, contexts and queues and kernel management.

The `cl2.hpp` uses the default device, context and queue if none is given. As I was not consistent with the default in the example above and thus different queues and contexts "owned" different objects.

I initially got rid of the `CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT` by rewriting how I manage kernels including adding:

```cpp
program.createKernels(&kernel_list)
```

And using that list to initialize the `KernelFunctor`.